# Uses of the verb "get". Pandora's box

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-in-context

**Hi!** I'm learning the language and I can't understand all the different meanings of the verb get in order to use all the meanings of the word... Is it there a trick, rule/s to identify when to use it? I find it very difficult to **get** the meaning of the verb  I feel like Tarzan writing so, sorry. Haha. I'm waiting for your answers!!

Comment: This question is too broad to be reasonably answered on this site. There are probably hundreds (if not thousands) of different specific ways to use *get*.

Comment: Like Jason says, this question seems a little too broad for our site. If you can ask a specific question about an example sentence with _get_, that would be better. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.